# Azure - Run bicep from registry via ARM REST api

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm looking into publishing bicep templates to a Bicep registry (ACR), and then deploying them via the ARM REST api. However the REST create deployment api only allows me to specify a templateSpec - I don't see any way to reference an ACR url. Is this possible, or do I need to use template specs for this?

For context, I need to create an automated service that can deploy resources when a particular event happens, e.g. add new customer -> spin up Azure resources xyz. Having my service use the REST api seems reasonable, and I'd prefer to use the bicep registry over template specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Content in the Bicep module registry can only be deployed from another Bicep file. Template specs can be deployed directly from the API, Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, and the Azure portal. You can even use UiFormDefinition to customize the portal deployment experience.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/modules) for more information.